# How much foundation do we get for free in $\sf ZFC$?

Tags: set-theory

In $\sf ZFC$ we have the axiom of infinity and thus can define the natural numbers $$\mathbb N \equiv \bigcap\{X:\emptyset\in X\land \forall n(n\in X\implies n\cup\{n\}\in X)\}.$$ From this it's not particularly hard (exercises 1.6 and 1.7 in Jech - *Set Theory*)  to prove that, firstly, every $n\in\mathbb N$ obeys foundation and secondly, $\mathbb N$ itself obeys it, all without explicitly using the axiom of foundation. My question is: does this extend to arbitrary finite sets or even other countable sets? If not, are there any other specific important examples for which we can verify foundation?

Comment: One can show that, in general, all ordinals $\alpha$ satisfy the property that $\alpha\notin \alpha$.

Comment: @Hayden Does that necessarily imply the pure form of foundation with every nonempty subset of $\alpha$ having a $\in$-minimal element? Excuse my ignorance, I'm quite new to set theory.

Comment: Quite alright, to be honest I don't know if that is equivalent to foundation, though I would assume not.  Still, it's at least a little bit of regularity that happens to hold for all ordinals, so I figured it was worth mentioning.  I'll look around to see if I can find something on the (non)equivalence of the statements, though.

Comment: I *really* don't understand the question. Are you asking how many sets are well-founded in $\sf ZFC$? Or are you asking about $\sf ZFC-Fnd$? Or are you talking about foundations of mathematics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the sets we define and use in the development of ordinary mathematics are automatically well-founded. Essentially, any set you can prove *exists* can also be proven to be well-founded without using the axiom of foundation.

The role of the axiom of foundation is not to tell us anything *new* about the sets we're already using, but merely to claim that *there are no other sets* than the well-founded ones. It puts a limit on which kinds of wild, spurious things may exist in a model of set theory without our asking for them, which is sometimes technically convenient -- but it doesn't say anything we don't already know about the sets we *want* to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The von Neumann herirarchy is defined as
$$V_0=\emptyset$$
$$V_{\alpha+1}=P(V_{\alpha})$$
$$V_{\lambda}=\cup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_{\alpha}$$

Now all elements of $V$ satisfy foundation. What foundation really means is that all sets belong to $V$. Since in practice all the sets we naturally deal with are already in $V$ foundation is not so essential to the development of set theory or mathematics.